# How do I change Google accounts on the Android app login?

Tags: support, android-app

I want to be able to log out of the Google account chosen for me by default. I can logout of Stack Exchange, but when I press the Google login button, the email I originally clicked (which isn't the account I normally use) is automatically selected. How do I select a different Google account?

Here is what I did:

1. Initially I opened the Stack Exchange app and I pressed the Google login option, and a screen popped up with three options, my three emails which I use on my phone.
2. I clicked one because I thought it was the one I normally use for Stack Exchange but it turns out it wasn't, so I logged off.
3. Then I clicked the Google login again and it didn't show me any options, it just assumed I wanted to use the email I initially did.

I want it to not assume this any more so I can use my regular account.

---

Okay definitely. Initially I opened the Stack Exchange app and I pressed the Google login option, and a screen popped up with three options, my three emails which I use on my phone. I clicked one because I thought it was the one I normally use for Stack Exchange, but it turns out it wasn't, so I logged off. Then I clicked the Google login again and it didn't show me any options, just assumed I wanted to use the email I initially did. I want it to not assume this any more so I can use my regular account.

Comment: Google is not part of Stack Exchange. You will have to log out from Google itself.

Comment: Can You number off the result you want, the steps your're taking, and the result you're getting, also screen shots help sometimes. Sorry if Im asking too much but that could make it easier for me or another user to try to help quicker, if you haven't found the solution already.

Comment: Okay definitely. Initially I opened the stackexchange app and I pressed the Google login option, and a screen popped up with three options, my three emails which I use on my phone. I clicked one because I thought it was the one I normally use for stackexchange but it turns out it wasn't, so I logged off. Then I clicked the Google login again and it didn't show me any options, just assumed I wanted to use the email I initially did. I want it to not assume this anymore so I can use my regular account.

Comment: OK cool, if possible have you tried to log out of the app?, sorry that I'm not familiar with the app, I have another device.

Answer (score 1):

Steps:
1.Uninstall the App. 
2.Go to Play Store , Switch to your preferred account there.
3.Reinstall the app
4.Now when you open the app again it should ask to you select your preferred account.
5.Also make sure Google Smart Lock is temporarily disabled [May not be needed in some cases.